# Не получается подключить сайт к бд

Tags: php, html, mysql

Проблема такова: на сайте есть input в который, пользователь записывает данные. Сделал отдельный файл php для того чтобы соеденить бд с сайтом, но ничего не происходит. Также записал одну строку кода в html. Все также не работает.
Код php:

```
<?php
$fio = $_POST['fio_user'];
$email = $_POST['email_input'];
$wallet = $_POST['account'];
// Параметры для подключения
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root"; // Логин БД
$db_password = "root"; // Пароль БД
$db_base = '...'; // Имя БД
$db_table = "..."; // Имя Таблицы БД

try {
    // Подключение к базе данных
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_base", $db_user, $db_password);
    // Устанавливаем корректную кодировку
    $db->exec("set names utf8");
    // Собираем данные для запроса
$data = array( 'fio_user' => $fio, 'email_input' => $email, 'account' => $wallet);
// Подготавливаем SQL-запрос
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $db_table ('fio_user', 'email_input', 'wallet') values (:fio, :email, :wallet)");
// Выполняем запрос с данными
$query->execute($data);
  ?>
```

и часть кода html:  <form method = "POST", action ="checker.php">

Comment: в тэге form между атрибутами method и action не должно быть запятой. Лучше приложить весь html код формы со вложенными элементами

Comment: ('fio_user', 'email_input', 'wallet') а передаете account в место wallet.. на первый взгляд если)